# Compare each row of two identical Datatables for changed values C#

Tags: c#

I need to compare two datatables which are having same schema and move the differences into another datatable. Below is my code which is not working fine:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("TableChanged");
dt1.Columns.Add("StateID",typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("StateInitial");
dt1.Columns.Add("IsActive");

dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, "GA", 1 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, "HI", 0 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, "ID", 1 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, "IL", 1 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, "IN", 0 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, "IA", 1 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 23, "MN", 0 });

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("TableOriginal");
dt2.Columns.Add("StateID", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("StateInitial");
dt2.Columns.Add("IsActive");

dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, "GA", 1 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, "HI", 1 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, "ID", 1 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, "IL", 0 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, "IN", 1 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, "IA", 1 });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 23, "MN", 1 });
var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<int>("StateID") equals table2.Field<int>("StateID")
              //where table1.Field<object>("IsActive") == "0"
              where table1.Field<string>("StateInitial") == table2.Field<string>("StateInitial") || table1.Field<object>("IsActive") == table2.Field<object>("IsActive") 
              select table1;
var missing = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              where !matched.Contains(table1)
              select table1;
```

After comparison, I want result like:

```
  StateID|StateInitial|IsActive
    11         "HI"         0
    13         "IL"         1
    14         "IN"         0
    23         "MN"         0
```

Comment: I think you want to change the `||` in your `where` clause to a `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataRowComparer.Default`, which compares every field of a `DataRow`, for the LINQ methods `Intersect` and `Except`. The latter gives you the missing rows, your desired result:

```
DataRowComparer<DataRow> fieldComparer = DataRowComparer.Default;
IEnumerable<DataRow> matched = dt1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(dt2.AsEnumerable(), fieldComparer);
IEnumerable<DataRow> missing = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), fieldComparer);
```

If you want to add the missing rows into a third table, you could use:

```
DataTable result = missing.CopyToDataTable();
```

But i suggest to use a different way because that throws an exception if there were no missing rows:

```
DataTable result = dt1.Clone(); // empty, same schema
foreach(DataRow row in missing)
    result.ImportRow(row);
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine but how to insert these missing rows to a new Datatable, could you please update?